# Keep values(or items) based on priority in an array(or list) which has multiple dictionaries and remove duplicates too

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, duplicates

```
Array_1 = [{'name': 'Anna','rank': 'first', 'roll_no': 'R1111','id': '1000'},{'name': 'Anna','rank': 'first', 'roll_no': 'R1111','id': '1000'},{'name': 'Anna','rank': 'second', 'roll_no': 'R1111','id': '1000'},{'name': 'Bob','rank': 'first', 'roll_no': 'R1112','id': '1001'},{'name': 'Charles','rank': 'third', 'roll_no': 'R1113','id': '1002'},{'name': 'Charles','rank': 'second', 'roll_no': 'R1113','id': '1002'},{'name': 'Darwin','rank': 'fourth', 'roll_no': 'R1114','id': '1003'},{'name': 'Darwin','rank': 'second', 'roll_no': 'R1114','id': '1003'},{'name': 'Darwin','rank': 'second', 'roll_no': 'R1114','id': '1003'},{'name': 'Eve','rank': 'fifth', 'roll_no': 'R1115','id': '1004'}]
```

I have an array with multiple dictionaries which have some duplicates. I want to **remove duplicates** and also **keep only values** based on **priority**.

 
My priority is **rank**: '**first**' then '**second**' then '**third**' then '**fourth**' then '**fifth**'
 ranks are fixed upto fifth

```
{'id': '1000', 'rank': 'first', 'roll_no': 'R1111', 'name': 'Anna'}
{'id': '1000', 'rank': 'first', 'roll_no': 'R1111', 'name': 'Anna'}
{'id': '1000', 'rank': 'second', 'roll_no': 'R1111', 'name': 'Anna'}
{'id': '1001', 'rank': 'first', 'roll_no': 'R1112', 'name': 'Bob'}
{'id': '1002', 'rank': 'third', 'roll_no': 'R1113', 'name': 'Charles'}
{'id': '1002', 'rank': 'second', 'roll_no': 'R1113', 'name': 'Charles'}
{'id': '1003', 'rank': 'fourth', 'roll_no': 'R1114', 'name': 'Darwin'}
{'id': '1003', 'rank': 'second', 'roll_no': 'R1114', 'name': 'Darwin'}
{'id': '1003', 'rank': 'second', 'roll_no': 'R1114', 'name': 'Darwin'}
{'id': '1004', 'rank': 'fifth', 'roll_no': 'R1115', 'name': 'Eve'}
```

I want like this

```
{'id': '1000', 'rank': 'first', 'roll_no': 'R1111', 'name': 'Anna'}
{'id': '1001', 'rank': 'first', 'roll_no': 'R1112', 'name': 'Bob'}
{'id': '1002', 'rank': 'second', 'roll_no': 'R1113', 'name': 'Charles'}
{'id': '1003', 'rank': 'second', 'roll_no': 'R1114', 'name': 'Darwin'}
{'id': '1004', 'rank': 'fifth', 'roll_no': 'R1115', 'name': 'Eve'}

Uniq = []
for i in range(len(Array_1)-1):
    if Array_1[i]["name"] != Array_1[i+1]["name"]:
        Uniq.append(Array_1[i])
Uniq.append(Array_1[-1])
```

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far and tell us what exactly is notworking. SO is no code-writing service.

Comment: check once i edited the question @MikeScotty

Comment: Why is this question put on hold for being *"too broad"*? It was pretty clear IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just needs iterating through the list and the order:

```
import pprint

l = [{'id': '1000', 'rank': 'first', 'roll_no': 'R1111', 'name': 'Anna'},
{'id': '1000', 'rank': 'first', 'roll_no': 'R1111', 'name': 'Anna'},
{'id': '1000', 'rank': 'second', 'roll_no': 'R1111', 'name': 'Anna'},
{'id': '1001', 'rank': 'first', 'roll_no': 'R1112', 'name': 'Bob'},
{'id': '1002', 'rank': 'third', 'roll_no': 'R1113', 'name': 'Charles'},
{'id': '1002', 'rank': 'second', 'roll_no': 'R1113', 'name': 'Charles'},
{'id': '1003', 'rank': 'fourth', 'roll_no': 'R1114', 'name': 'Darwin'},
{'id': '1003', 'rank': 'second', 'roll_no': 'R1114', 'name': 'Darwin'},
{'id': '1003', 'rank': 'second', 'roll_no': 'R1114', 'name': 'Darwin'},
{'id': '1004', 'rank': 'fifth', 'roll_no': 'R1115', 'name': 'Eve'}]

order = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth']
l2 = []
list_of_names = []
for elem in l:
    if elem['name'] not in list_of_names:
        list_of_names.append(elem['name'])
for name in list_of_names:
    for order_elem in order:
        for elem in l:
            if elem['rank'] == order_elem and elem['name'] == name:
                l2.append(elem)
                break
        else:
            continue
        break

pprint.pprint(l2, indent=4)
```

Comment: I am not getting as I asked in question. It just sorting based on `rank`. **Check you code once**

Comment: @mrCarnivore I'm just going to delete my answer, I was just trying to show a potential alternative using pandas.

Comment: @AtHeartEngineer: I was just writing a reply when you deleted the answer. It is always good to provide a second answer with a different approach. You were not far off. Maybe with a little more work your solution would have worked as well!

Comment: Thanks @mrCarnivore...

Answer (score 2):

You can try using [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to first group the names together, then sort those names based on rank and pick the highest rank from each sorted list:

```
from itertools import groupby

data = [{'id': '1000', 'rank': 'first', 'roll_no': 'R1111', 'name': 'Anna'},
        {'id': '1000', 'rank': 'first', 'roll_no': 'R1111', 'name': 'Anna'},
        {'id': '1000', 'rank': 'second', 'roll_no': 'R1111', 'name': 'Anna'},
        {'id': '1001', 'rank': 'first', 'roll_no': 'R1112', 'name': 'Bob'},
        {'id': '1002', 'rank': 'third', 'roll_no': 'R1113', 'name': 'Charles'},
        {'id': '1002', 'rank': 'second', 'roll_no': 'R1113', 'name': 'Charles'},
        {'id': '1003', 'rank': 'fourth', 'roll_no': 'R1114', 'name': 'Darwin'},
        {'id': '1003', 'rank': 'second', 'roll_no': 'R1114', 'name': 'Darwin'},
        {'id': '1003', 'rank': 'second', 'roll_no': 'R1114', 'name': 'Darwin'},
        {'id': '1004', 'rank': 'fifth', 'roll_no': 'R1115', 'name': 'Eve'}]

orders = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth'] 

rank_priority = []

# group based on names
for _, group in groupby(data, lambda x: x['name']):

    # create an ordered dictionary based on ranks
    order_dict = {rank: index for index, rank in enumerate(orders)}

    # sort lists based on dictionary ordering above
    sorted_ranks = sorted(list(group), key = lambda x: order_dict[x['rank']])

   # extract highest rank
    rank_priority.append(sorted_ranks[0])

print(rank_priority)
```

Which Outputs:

```
[{'name': 'Anna', 'id': '1000', 'rank': 'first', 'roll_no': 'R1111'}, 
 {'name': 'Bob', 'id': '1001', 'rank': 'first', 'roll_no': 'R1112'}, 
 {'name': 'Charles', 'id': '1002', 'rank': 'second', 'roll_no': 'R1113'}, 
 {'name': 'Darwin', 'id': '1003', 'rank': 'second', 'roll_no': 'R1114'}, 
 {'name': 'Eve', 'id': '1004', 'rank': 'fifth', 'roll_no': 'R1115'}]
```

Comment: very sophisticated. Thanks for your help.